# How to use traci and sumo in python?

Tags: python, sumo

I am trying to simulate an intersection with traffic light and detectors and train a machine learning classifier to use the information from the detectors to set the traffic light phase.

I am able to run the simulation using:

```
import traci
traci.start(sumoCmd) 
step = 0
while step < 1000:
    traci.simulationStep()
    step += 1
traci.close()
```

However, I do not know how to get information about cars. I have e2 detectors, but I don't know how to use their output. I don't understand traci and sumo documentation.

I tried this code:

```
import traci
traci.start(sumoCmd) 
step = 0
lanearea = traci._lanearea.LaneAreaDomain()
detlist = lanearea.getIDList()
while step < 1000:
    traci.simulationStep()
    print([lanearea.getLastStepVehicleNumber(det) for det in detlist])
    step += 1
traci.close()
```

but it does not work. I am getting this error

```
detlist = lanearea.getIDList()
return self._getUniversal(tc.ID_LIST, "")
result = self._connection._sendReadOneStringCmd(self._cmdGetID, varID, objectID)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_sendReadOneStringCmd'
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this code? Or more generally, if anyone knows it, how to use any function in: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/TraCI/Lane_Area_Detector_Value_Retrieval or any other ways to get information about cars.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: In particular, you seem to ask us to make up for the lack of sumo/traci documentation and examples.  This seems *very* broad and quite off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If you have a particular example that needs help, please post a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and someone will probably try to help.

Comment: I would prefer to have a more general answer, but if you want to give me an answer to only one coding bug, there is this one that I mention in my question: 
    import traci
    traci.start(sumoCmd) 
    step = 0
    lanearea = traci._lanearea.LaneAreaDomain()
    detlist = lanearea.getIDList()
    while step < 1000:
        traci.simulationStep()
        print([lanearea.getLastStepVehicleNumber(det) for det in detlist])
        step += 1
    traci.close()

Comment: I am getting this error

    detlist = lanearea.getIDList()
    return self._getUniversal(tc.ID_LIST, "")
    result = self._connection._sendReadOneStringCmd(self._cmdGetID, varID, objectID)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_sendReadOneStringCmd'

Comment: Please edit such things into you question.  As you can see, code and output do *not* format well in comments.  Make sure that your code example is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to instantiate the lanearea yourself. Just use `traci.lanearea.getIDList()` and `traci.lanearea.getLastStepVehicleNumber(det)` so your program should look like:

```
import traci
traci.start(sumoCmd) 
step = 0
detlist = traci.lanearea.getIDList()
while step < 1000:
    traci.simulationStep()
    print([traci.lanearea.getLastStepVehicleNumber(det) for det in detlist])
    step += 1
```

Also the close is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following way to get vehicle ID list

```
vehicle_id_list = traci.vehicle.getIDList()
```

And then IDs obtained can be used to get various parameters like

1. waiting time: `traci.vehicle.getAccumulatedWaitingTime(vehicle_id)`
2. road id: `traci.vehicle.getRoadID(vehicle_id)`
   and so on.